# Having trouble with my BST findMax

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble with my findMax() method in my BST. When I run it I get a Stack overflow error (ha). I just can't seem to figure out what exactly im doing wrong? Any insight would be much appreciated. This is the code I have so far.

```
public AnyType findMax() throws EmptyBSTException {

    if ( isEmpty() )
        throw new EmptyBSTException();

    return findMax( root ).getElement();

} 


private BinaryNode<AnyType> findMax( BinaryNode<AnyType> node ) {

           if(root.getRight() == null) {
            return root; 
           } 
           else {
            return findMax(root.getRight())
}

            }
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Just by inspection, I can't spot an error. I guess that either the tree reference structure is corrupted and represents a path of infinite height or the tree is excessively large; could that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly want to write `node` instead of `root` everywhere in your second function.

Answer (score 0):

As Codor mentioned, this may have to do with the tree you're testing your code on. Make sure that none of the right childs of path from root to leaves have a circular reference back up to one of the parents.

But if the tree itself is super huge try a non-recursive alternative (which doesn't have the stack overhead)

```
public AnyType findMax() throws EmptyBSTException {

   if ( isEmpty() )
      throw new EmptyBSTException();

   BinaryNode<AnyType> node = root;
   while (node.getRight() != null){

     node = node.getRight();
   }

   return node.getElement();
}
```